# Are these strings the correct output to verify keys for file checksum?

Tags: apache-http-server, netbeans, checksum, verification, certutil

I'm trying to verify the integrity of the files before installing a downloaded copy of Netbeans from the Apache.org site, per their suggestion.  I'm not having luck verifying I am using the tools correctly and/or how to correctly read the results.

I used one tool called File Checksum Utility by blqsoftware, which I downloaded from the SourceForge.net site. The instructions are really lacking in my opinion. I'm not sure about the results, but it didn't look good, so I used a second tool in Windows 10- certUtil -hashfile at the command prompt.  Each time it claimed a successful completion of the command, indicating a SHA1 hash of the file.

This is example of how I used the certUtil command and the result:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>certutil -hashfile C:\Users\admin\Downloads\netBeans\apache-netbeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe
SHA1 hash of C:\Users\admin\Downloads\netBeans\apache-netbeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe:
b9b94a787f6da1498d542f9da2595fdd0914ecc0
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

These are the results from the downloaded netbeans executable file, as well as the .txt files where I copied the PGP ASC/signature and SHA-512 contents:

b9b94a787f6da1498d542f9da2595fdd0914ecc0

099223c7e088271f1e9753665b891eed67a89e59

f29257fa61656c3bd9a00194299cde6f554cf18b

63ab3ef3d58a8dcc310a1a4b11492885314cf17e

baa1a27b53862cbb95ae79e3c6cc5049ce251aab

The first one is from the netbeans executable and the others are results generated from the keys I copied from Apache's links.

If these are legitimate results, then what now? Try downloading the netbeans again?

Answer (score 1):

> Each time it claimed a successful completion of the command,
> indicating a SHA1 hash of the file.

You need to include the option "SHA512" at the end of the certUtil command for it to give the SHA512 hash instead of the default SHA1:

```
certutil -hashfile C:\Users\admin\Downloads\netBeans\apache-netbeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe SHA512
```

This will produce the SHA512 hash of the file which you would compare to the SHA512 hash value shown on the [Apache site](https://downloads.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans/12.0/Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe.sha512):

> 525d61838c0cb82a6234bff1984b9886324eccdb0320875c639889e64299b1b621d01ca524ff0a770ac65ef05aad367722977066cf017369932c10f55992e90f  ./Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe

If the two values match, you can be reasonably assured of the downloaded file's integrity.

Comment: I did get other strings with Fuzzy's suggestion, but still no joy: 004944e00d91037e559e9bf1fcbd965adbe94c13f8360abbc8a1c5c01383e43aacd597afd440429adf318bceab9a1c8b66cff349da7329a8e9eaabf8618ebae7

81cf124ddca456bd2d38fd67756bf1666d11a1eafa85d017cbfcdc044667daec9ebaa966ab58cabdba394fe2d2a8933ec50faa727ea0cb8f863ebbace551e971

9f9e04aa45254723e62cc93478267ceb4d5c767cd1acfae8d8f1d66a733ac5df605de0da4611bd2c3e5f8525c16d4ace032199562de351d77106918808ea6742

Comment: I read that certUtil doesn't always work correctly. Other suggestions? I downloaded Netbeans a second time from mirror/backup site, and it has same key as the first one downloaded.

Comment: I don't understand what other items besides the file Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-windows-x64.exe you are hashing. That .exe file is the only item you need to hash and compare that hash value to the one given on the Apache site.

Comment: It's my understanding a key or signature is given separately from the file to be downloaded.  Looking at the contents of the files that make up these keys/signatures, it appears they need to be hashed as well.  Hash both with the correct algorithm, and if you get the same result on both (they're a match), then your file is good.

Comment: @BikerJ: No, that's not how signature files work. They do involve _a_ hash, yes, but you will never get the correct result by using any regular hash tool – two different files will never (well, _normally_ never) produce the same hash. You need to use a specific tool for verifying those signatures instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar utility in windows 10 powershell; Get -FileHash.
Netbeans did not want to install because it couldn't find any JDK already installed (I was under the impression the Netbeans app included it), so I downloaded JDK 15.0 from Oracle's page, and they had a key for that, which I also downloaded. They use one of the other algorithms, but the Get -FileHash worked, and the binary checksums matched, so at least I know now what good results (okay file) look like.  I used the Get -FileHash on the netbeans executable and it's associated keys, but still no luck. Apache appears to be doing some reorganization/shuffling on their websites, so maybe this is part of the issue?

For grins, I'll go back and try the certUtil with the JDK to see what it churns out.

Thanks Fuzzy Drawings for your suggestions.

Here's results for the JDK. String in middle is with the Get -FileHash command with Powershell.  The last one is with certUtil -Hashfile w/ MSDOS/command console.

sha256: 736cd1e22378adf5fc8664c9e9245f4793ae0f8fe43dd848ca361ee5d71f5553

```
    736CD1E22378ADF5FC8664C9E9245F4793AE0F8FE43DD848CA361EE5D71F5553

    736cd1e22378adf5fc8664c9e9245f4793ae0f8fe43dd848ca361ee5d71f5553
```

Answer (score 0):

> I used a second tool in Windows 10- certUtil -hashfile at the command prompt. Each time it claimed a successful completion of the command, indicating a SHA1 hash of the file

Hashing tools cannot verify anything on their own. They will always indicate success when used this way, because the only thing they do is algorithmically *generate* a hash for the given input (which cannot fail), but they have nothing to *compare* it against – no way of knowing whether that hash matches what you expect.

When a website wants you to verify the download using e.g. SHA1 or another hash, it will actually publish the expected hash values next to the download link – and it is up to you to compare each digit of the generated hash against the published one.

Some tools can compare hashes automatically, but only when given *two* files (the original, and the list of hashes – e.g. a `sha1sums.txt` file is common). Windows' Certutil cannot do this.

---

However, when the website offers you verification through PGP signatures, then a hashing program is the completely wrong tool for the job. Merely hashing the .asc file tells you nothing useful about the .exe file nor the other way around.

*(It probably doesn't even tell you anything about the .asc file itself if you copypasted things into by hand. Keep in mind that hash tools count every byte – an extra space here or a newline there will result in a different hash.)*

To deal with signatures, you need to use a program which understands that specific signature format – for PGP .asc signatures and key files you need PGP-compatible software, such as GnuPG (Gpg4win). It will actually interpret the .asc or .sig file, perform its own hashing, and verify the digital signature relationship between the .exe and the PGP key which signed it.

```
gpg --verify netbeans.asc netbeans.exe
```

(However, these tools only tell you that key X indeed signed file Y – but they still don't know whether that key X is the one that was *supposed to* be signing this file. That's still your job to verify somehow. Again, the website will usually publish the official PGP keys somewhere near the download links.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I know the hashing tools, at least the ones on a command line/in a console don't verify.  One has to visually compare the strings generated to see if they match.

Answer (score -1):

For those who want to verify it easier.
You can try online checksum tools https://md5-checksum.com , support md5, sha256, sha1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).